# How to do Python string formatting without quotes?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, string, string-formatting

I am writing a Python function that does string formatting for a SQL query. Due to this, the string formatting needs to be very precise.

Currently, I have a SQL query template string and I am trying to fill out values using `str.format()`.

Imagine something like:

```
sql_query_template.format(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
```

An issue I am running into is the placement of quotation marks of Python strings.

Desired result:

```
(ARRAY[‘blah’, ‘25’], ‘test_group_1’, '243'),(ARRAY[‘blah2’, '12'], ‘test_group_2', '21')
```

- The goal is to create tuples while using `ARRAY[]` keyword, it is important for `ARRAY[]` to not turn into `‘ARRAY[]’` or for the entire tuple to get encased by quotes -> SQL needs to treat the keywords as keywords.

Current result:

```
(‘ARRAY[blah, 25]’, ‘test_group_1’, '243'),(‘ARRAY[blah2, 12]’, ‘test_group_2', '21')
```

- Here `ARRAY[]` is being wrapped in quotation marks (ex: `‘ARRAY[blah, 25]'`)
- This is problematic because Presto won’t recognize `ARRAY` as a keyword and is treating `‘ARRAY[]’` as a string

Current snippet:

```py
# dummy example:
test_dict = json.loads(
    json.dumps(
        [
            {
                "parameter_1": ["blah", "25"],
                "parameter_2": "test_group_1",
                "parameter_3": "243",
            },
            {
                "parameter_1": ["blah2", "12"],
                "parameter_2": "test_group_2",
                "parameter_3": "21",
            },
        ]
    )
)

list_of_tuples = []
for dict in test_dict:
    list_of_tuples.append(
        (
            "ARRAY[{}]".format(",".join(dict[“parameter_1"])),
            dict["parameter_2"],
            f"{dict[parameter_3]}",
        )
    )
formatted_tuples = ",".join(
    str(tup) for tup in list_of_tuples
)
print(sql_query_template.format(arg1=formatted_tuples))
```

Is it possible to write Python code in such a way where string formatting will insert certain parts that aren’t wrapped up in quotes?

Comment: please consider marking the question as answered (gray tickmark besides the answer) and upvoting if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The key part seems to be: `"ARRAY[{}]".format(",".join(dict[“parameter_1"])),` which is very close but not what you seem to need.

The problem is

`"ARRAY[{}]".format(param)`

which you would have to amend with `'` so that you get the quoting you need:

`"ARRAY['{}']".format(param)`

you can check this works using MWE:

```
param = 44
print("ARRAY['{}']".format(param))
```

gives output:

```
ARRAY['12']
```